# Two separate users saving same PFObject

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

If two separate users have the same PFObject locally and `user1` saves the object first then `user2` calls to save it next(like below), will the array only contain `user2` objectId or both objectIds?

```
    [object addUniqueObject:[[PFUser currentUser]objectId] forKey:@"invite"];
    [object saveInBackground];
```

And if it only contains `user2`id is the only way to make sure the object saves properly is to fetch it right before I save it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Parse API docs](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.Object.html#addUnique), `addUniqueObject` is an atomic operation, so similarly to `increment`, it should still work in a race condition (i.e. if either of the objects being saved hasn't been fetched).

You shouldn't have to fetch both objects for it to save properly. If it's not working, it might be because you're overriding it somewhere else (like in cloud code), but the `addUniqueObject` call should allow both objects to save